# How to save results for each outcome?

Tags: for-loop, save, julia

I am trying to save results for each outcome.

For example,

```
list = [:A, :B]
for i in 1:length(list)
    result$i = lm((@eval @formula($i ~ x1 + x2)), data)
end
```

So that I can save the results for each outcome like result1, result2, … ,

then export each result to csv file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an array of results, like

```
results = [lm((@eval @formula($i ~ x1 + x2)), data) for i in 1:length(list)]
```

or iteratively push the results

```
results = []
for i in 1:length(list)
    push!(results, lm((@eval @formula($i ~ x1 + x2)), data))
end
```